# Translating a integer to a key

Tags: python, input, terminal, key, curses

I have a very basic terminal UI in curses that looks like this:

```
│Option:                       Status:   Key: 
│description of option 1       [ON]       <267>
│description of option 2       [OFF]      <102>
```

The key is the key you have to press for the status to change. In the curses module (or in general) how can I tansform a key integer to a name?

If my key is ord('f') which is 102 I can chr(102) to get 'f' printed on the screen. But if my key is curses.KEY_F3 which is 267 I get funny symbols for chr(267). How can I print 'F3' from just the integer 267?

This is the copied output with chr() but in the console there is a box with a ? behind the Ä

```
│Option:                       Status:   Key:
│description of option 1       [ON]       <Ä>
│description of option 2       [OFF]      <f>
```

Comment: If curses doesn't have special function to translate it then you have to create own dictionary with numbers and names. Or put manually text `"F3"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need [curses.keyname](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.keyname).

> **curses.keyname(k)** Return the name of the key numbered k. The name of a
>   key generating printable ASCII character is the key’s character. The
>   name of a control-key combination is a two-character string consisting
>   of a caret followed by the corresponding printable ASCII character.
>   The name of an alt-key combination (128–255) is a string consisting of
>   the prefix ‘M-‘ followed by the name of the corresponding ASCII
>   character.

Comment: This is giving me <KEY_F(3)> and <F> though it is probably the closest I get to what I want and I just will handle the string in some way.